# Como pegar o valor de uma lista de ckeckboxes com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, dom

Já tentei o seguinte:

```
<input name="chklista" id="chk01" value="01" type="checkbox" />01<br />
<input name="chklista" id="chk02" value="02" type="checkbox" />02<br />
<input name="chklista" id="chk03" value="03" type="checkbox" />03<br />    
<br />
<input id="btn01" type="button" value="button" onclick="teste();" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="div01">
</div>
```

é na função:

```
function teste() {
    //não funciona
    //var chklista = $('#chklista').val();
    var chklista = $('input[name="chklista"]').val();    
    var chk01 = $('#chk01 checked').val();
    var chk02 = $('#chk02 checked').val();
    var chk03 = $('#chk03 checked').val();
    $('#div01').html("por nome: <br />chklista: " + chklista + "<br /><br />por id: <br />chk01: " + chk01 + "<br />chk02: " + chk02 + "<br />chk03: " + chk03 + "<br />");
}
```

a saída foi essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando eu queria algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você deve usar assim:

```
var chk01 = $('#chk01').is(':checked');
var chk02 = $('#chk02').is(':checked');
var chk03 = $('#chk03').is(':checked');
```

Experimente:

```js
function teste() {
    var chklista = $('input[name="chklista"]:checked').toArray().map(function(check) { 
        return $(check).val(); 
    });   
    var chk01 = $('#chk01').is(':checked');
    var chk02 = $('#chk02').is(':checked');
    var chk03 = $('#chk03').is(':checked');
    $('#div01').html("por nome: <br />chklista: " + chklista + "<br /><br />por id: <br />chk01: " + chk01 + "<br />chk02: " + chk02 + "<br />chk03: " + chk03 + "<br />");
}

$('#btn01').bind('click', teste);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="chklista" id="chk01" value="01" type="checkbox" />01<br />
<input name="chklista" id="chk02" value="02" type="checkbox" />02<br />
<input name="chklista" id="chk03" value="03" type="checkbox" />03<br />    
<br />
<input id="btn01" type="button" value="CLIQUE AQUI PARA TESTAR" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="div01">
</div>
```

O trecho:

```
$('input[name="chklista"]:checked').toArray().map(function(check) { 
    return $(check).val(); 
});
```

Simplesmente busca todos os inputs com o name "chklista" que estão checados, transforma o objeto jquery que guarda uma referencia para todos eles em um array convencional, então pegamos esse array e mapeamos cada elemento da DOM para seu valor, que você definiu no HTML